# Session.Timeout always prints 60

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, session-timeout

**Context**

I have an `ASP.Net` web application created in `IIS` as below:

```
Default Web Site --> Testing
```

That Testing is an application which uses `DefaultAppPool` as `Default Web Site`.

In `Default Web Site` and Testing, session is "In Process" and timeout is 20 minutes default. There is no timeout defined in `web.config.`

Problem is when I print timeout on `ASP.Net` page, it always shows 60. I have `reset IIS` several times but same issue.

**Question**

Why is it showing me 60 when timeout is 20 in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check this by going to:

- "ApplicationPool"
- Your application pool.
- Go to "Properties"
- "Performance" tab.
- See value in "Shutdown worker processes after being idle for (time in minutes)"

When you use the default session state mode of "InProc" (In Process), as you are, the Session State data is very fragile and is lost whenever the AppPool recycles.
also, here is a good article on how to troublshoot session states http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TroubleshootingExpiredASPNETSessionStateAndYourOptions.aspx

Comment: But the question is why it is showing 60? I tried two different machines and both have same problem.

Comment: @FrankMartin did you check value of the shutdown worker process?

Comment: There is no "Shutdown worker processes after being idle for (time in minutes)". There is "Idle Time-out (minutes)" which I have set to 20 minutes like session time out.

Comment: do you have IIS 7.5 ?